# Оформление терминов или "буквы Бога"

Tags: пунктуация

И здесь, и в других местах часто приходится писать слова, которые входят в предложение не как его члены, не с основным значением, а именно как слово. Например:

> Термин "параллелограмм" введен ...

или (из форумного вопроса)

> В выражении "Заставь дурака богу молиться" - Бог с прописной или строчной буквы?

Слово "параллелограмм" взято в кавычки, а "Бог" - нет. Но у Бога нет никаких букв, ни прописных, ни строчных. Они есть только у слова "Бог".

Значит ли это, что в подобных случаях всегда надо брать слово в кавычки, чтобы отличить его смысл от него самого? Вроде так, но получается как-то громоздко. Думаю, на письме (вернее, при наборе с клавиатуры) можно заменить кавычки другими способами выделения: *курсивом* или `другим шрифтом`.

Какие есть правила на этот счет?
**Дополнение**. Мне самой не совсем ясен мой вопрос. Если кто понял его лучше, чем я, - прошу помочь в формулировании.
Попробую так: я вижу два близких случая, когда просится ставить кавычки.
 1. Использование слова не по смыслу, а в качестве элемента словаря. Например, так: "Это очень хорошая шишка, и она должна с чем-то рифмоваться". Во второй части предложения *шишка* уже другая: это не вещь, а слово. Нужно ли при таком употреблении ставить кавычки (или как-то выделять текст)? Тот же случай с "Богом". 
 2. Использование слова как названия. Например: функция *summary*. Здесь *summary* используется не прямому смыслу (резюме, сводка), а в качестве названия функции языка программирования. Причем само слово "функция" может быть опущено. Здесь тоже надо как-то графически подчеркнуть различие.

Comment: Хороший вопрос. Интересно будет почитать ответы. Сам задумывался. 

В английском языке в таких случаях часто используется выделение подобного слова курсивом.

Comment: Я читала книгу по программированию в 1С, там была целая стройная система выделения терминов разного порядка. Если ее не употреблять, там от кавычек рябило бы в глазах. И в других книгах по программированию также.  
Это, правда, вызывало затруднения при переводе автоматическим переводчиком.

Comment: Не только там. В люой книге по пракраммировнию (и не только) кавычки щаменяют на разного рода шрифтоговые выделения. Обилие же потенцитальных кавычек (или мест для них) объясняетмя тем, что книги жто посвящены описанию языка - и следовательно написаны по сути на метаязыке. Со всеми вытекающими последствиями в виде обилия специфичесикх терминов, которым так или иначе надо дать определения - и использовать в в дальнейшем как термин, а не в обычном значении.

Comment: Нашла один из многих вопросов на этом форуме, где отсутствие кавычек (или другого выделения) делает текст трудночитаемым:  

> слово вот в предложении это обстоятельство?  

Впрочем, здесь и со знаками препинания туго...

Comment: Еще один смешной пример отсутствия кавычек:  
> Старуха Изергиль состоит из трех частей.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правила использования шрифтов для верстки книг, периодики безусловно есть: общие и разработанные дизайнерами конкретного издания. В специализированном справочнике по набору и верстке (Гиленсона) не нашла параграфа на эту тему. Кое-что есть [здесь](http://www.fontov.net/podbor-shrifta), но конкретно о выделении "терминов" (как в нашем случае) ничего не сказано. Мне кажется, это негласное правило: брать в кавычки или же выделять другим шрифтом (часто курсивом) слово в специфическом значении, иначе нарушится логика. Обилие кавычек действительно нежелательно, так как это усложняет читаемость. Курсив - неплохая альтернатива для них.

> Значит ли это, что в подобных случаях
> всегда надо брать слово в кавычки,
> чтобы отличить его смысл от него
> самого?

Выделять как-то надо: или брать в кавычки, или делать курсивом.

Comment: Да, согласна. Из-за этого у меня иногда возникают недоумения при чтении здешних вопросов. Например, читаю фразу и только потом догадываюсь, что она относится не к содержанию сообщения, а является примером, о котором задается вопрос. Например, на разбор предложения или на пунктуацию.

Answer (score 0):

По поводу Бога и параллелограмма ничего сказать не могу, ибо вопроса не понял. Действительно, очень напоминает спор на тему чем "имя Бога отличается от Бога".

Термин берется в кавычки по той простой причне что предполагается первое его с ним читающего. В дальнейшем кавычки не используются. Или по причине наличия при нем родового слова. Точно так же можно написать <<Термин "Бог" введен Ананасовым и Протурберанцевым в раьботе  - и проч.>> 
При этом в родительном падеже даже эти кавычки опускаются: <<Понятие Бога введено Имерековым  в работе "О Боге и Его имени">>.

Выделнеие курсивом взамен кавычек давно и продуктивнол использует в полиграфических изданиях. С появлением интернета перекочевало и туда.  Хотя лично я по некоторым причинам стараюсь пока не далать этого в текстах общего содержания (т.е. предназначенных для чтения не только подготовленным читателем).

Comment: Я, похоже, не смогла четко задать вопрос, сама это чувствую. Дело не совсем в терминах, а именно в мета-употреблении слов (если понятно, о чем я).  
Сравните:  

> В параллелограмме ABCD сторона AB...  
> В слове "параллелограмм" три буквы "л".

А иногда родовое обозначение типа "слово" не пишется. Например, так:  

> the format of __genetics__ is not compressed,

Здесь genetics - название функции языка, а не "генетика". По русски здесь проблемы бы не было в силу использования разных алфавитов.

Comment: Так вот и сравните разницу в "мета-употреблении" родового слова. 
Слово "параллелограмм", тело "параллелограмм", Ффрма "параллолелаграмм" - и проч. Речь о параллелограмме как таковом.
Не в слове "слово" дело, а в том, что дальнейшее уточняет понятие, является видовым при родовом. Если хотите - "называет его", но это не совсем точное  употребление, да и не суть вопроса о причинах выделения. Выделяется именно как видовое при родовом, или как впервые вводимый в данном контексте термин.   
В остальных случаях речь не идет о родовом слове. Имя в "Имя Бога" - не есть родовое для Бог.

Comment: По поводу genetics ничего сказать не могу, дело в том что в технической литературе на английском используется столько всяких неоговоренных нигде соглашений, что непосвященному там делать несего. При всем том, интуитивно они понятны большинству читающих.

Comment: То есть Вы считаете, что так писать не надо:
 > В выражении "Заставь дурака богу молиться" - "Бог" с прописной или строчной буквы?  

последние кавычки не нужны?

Comment: Вообще-то непосредственно я на эту тему не я думал...
Скажем так. Необязательны. Но можно и поставить для наглядности. Здесь просматривается опущенное родовой слово: <<в [слове] "Бог">>.
Хотя в данно контексте, видимо, даже при наличии родового слова можно опустить.  Вообще это уже уходит в область корректуры, а корректор из миня - хуже чем никакой. Лучше у профессионалов спросить.

Answer (score 0):

В выражении "Заставь дурака Богу молиться..." слово "Бог" нужно писать с прописной буквы, т. к. здесь действует это правило: 
(Большой толковый словарь): БОГ [бох], -а, зват. Боже; мн. боги, богов; м.
1. [с прописной буквы] только ед. По религиозным представлениям:
творец неба и земли, всего сущего; всеведущий высший разум, управляющий миром; всеобщее мировое начало (имеет множество имён: Творец, Создатель, Всевышний, Вседержитель, Всемогущий и др.; в христианстве един в трёх лицах: Бог Отец, Бог Сын, Бог Дух Святой). Господь Бог (почтит.). Верить в Бога. Молиться, служить Богу. Побойся Бога!
По поводу всего остального: тут по ситуации. Например, если стоит слово "термин": (Существует такой термин, как ...), то дальнейшее слово идет в кавычках. Но если в предложении встречается оборот "так называемый", кавычки не нужны (... так называемый золотой стандарт) и т. д..

Comment: Извините, но Вы отвечаете не на мой вопрос. То, что написано с отступом от левого края - цитата, вопрос другого человека (уже отвеченный). Меня же интересует второе включение слова "Бог" - после кавычек. Нужно ли его графически выделять (как это делаю я в предыдущем предложении)?